# Calculating $\iint (x+y) \, dx \, dy$

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

By using the change of variable $u=x+y$ , $v=x$ evaluate
$$\iint_{Ta} (x+y) \, dx \, dy$$
where $Ta$ is the region in the $xy$ plane bounded by the $x$ and $y$ axes and the line $x+y = a$.

Update: I have since worked out the Jacobian = -1
so am now onto:
$$\iint_{Ta} (x+y) \, dx \, dy$$
$$=\iint_{Ta} (v+u-v) \, du \, dv$$
since $x=v$ and $y=u-v$, so
$$\iint_{Ta} u \, du \, dv$$
I am still struggling with what to put as the limits though!

Comment: Where does your problem lie? Calculating the Jacobian? What the reparametrised region is?

Comment: @Almentoe the region

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at $T_a = \{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 0\leq x\leq a, 0\leq y\leq a-x\}$ using the transformation $x=v, y=u-v$

Then $T_a' = \{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 0 \leq v\leq a, 0\leq u-v\leq a-v\} \\ \quad = \{(u,v)\in\Bbb R^2\mid 0\leq v\leq a, v\leq u\leq a\}$

$$P_\textsf{answer}=\int_0^a\int_{v}^a u\operatorname d u \operatorname d v$$

Answer (score 1):

I find it helpful to draw pictures of the regions and label the edges and vertices. Here’s the original region $Ta$, labeled S in the picture:

[image]

Since $x=v$, the segment labeled B will get mapped to the $v$-axis. Similarly, $x+y=u$, so the segment labeled C will get mapped to $u=a$. That leaves the segment along the $y$-axis, which corresponds to $u=v$:

[image]

Note that, with this orientation of the $u$- and $v$-axes, the orientation of the region is reversed. That’s consistent with the value that you worked out for the determinant of the Jacobian, $-1$. You should be able to work out the limits for the iterated integral from this.